# How to repeat text fields that retrieve data by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code which retrieve data by ajax from the database and can add unlimited text field:

```
<div class="input" id="itemRows">
    <div class="clone">
        <style>
            .txtHint {
                width:95%;
                padding:10px 6px;
                border-bottom:solid 3px #06C;
                background-color:#f1f1f1;
                margin-right:5px;
            }
        </style>
        <input onchange="showUser(this.value)" type="text" class="clientphone" placeholder="رقم العميل" name="clientmergedid[]" />
        <input type="text" class="clientdes" placeholder="صفة العميل" name="clientmergeddes[]" />
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
        <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if (str == "") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "searchuser/getuser.php?clientmergedid=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
        <div id="txtHint" class="txtHint">بيانات العميل</div>
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
    </div> <a href="#" class="add" rel=".clone">إضافة المزيد</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">إزالة</a>';
            $('a.add').relCopy({
                append: removeLink
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
    <input onClick="addRow(this.form);" class="clientadd" type="button" value="جديد" />
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is it can only retrieve data for the first `txtHint` div. How can it make the same for other inputs?

Comment: id of an element must be unique, so there should be only one element with the id `txtHint`

Comment: i knew that i'm asking how to give the new repeatable field a new function with the new id

Answer (score 1):

To your initial question, give each input a class, and then bind the `change` hander to elements of that class. That way you can have any number of inputs have that behavior:

```
<input class="my_class" type="text">
<input class="my_class" type="text">

jQuery(function () {
   jQuery('.my_class').on('change', function () {
      var the_input = jQuery(this);
      console.log("My new value is " + the_input.val());
      /// your ajax code goes here, and has access to the_input
   });
});
```

Exmple here: http://jsfiddle.net/3k3TL/

Also, since you appear to be using jQuery already, I'd suggest using it's [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method for your ajax call instead of your existing code.

Comment: i couldn't make it run

Comment: Is the Fiddle not doing what you expect, or it does what you want, but you are having trouble implementing your own version?

Comment: OK, perhaps you could explain what it was you expected? My code handles the onChange event for any number of text inputs, which is what you were asking for. If that's not the case, perhaps you could explain what you were really after.